# Problem of init array of structs with list data

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, linked-list

I found myself troubleshooting for quite time and try to figure out what is wrong with my function.
I must say that I'm not 100% sure if this the correct syntax to do what I want.
I've got this function that suppose to initialize a 1D array of structs with list data.
Everything before that function worked and tested.
This is the problematic func:

```
Three* createThreeArr(Three** arr, ListThree** head, int counter)
{
    int i = 0;
    ListThree* pIndex = *head;
    *arr = (Three*) calloc(counter,sizeof(Three));
    for (i = 0; i < counter ; i++)
    {
        (arr[i])->col   = pIndex->data.col;
        (arr[i])->row   = pIndex->data.row;
        (arr[i])->value = pIndex->data.value;
        pIndex = pIndex->next;
    }
     return *arr;
}
```

I'm able to insert in the first iteration but I have an Exception thrown in VS19.
This is how I pass the params:

```
*arr = createThreeArr(arr,head,counter);
```

Those are the structs:

```
typedef struct Three 
{
  int value;
  int row;
  int col;
}Three;

typedef struct ListThree
{
  struct Three data;
  struct List* next;
}ListThree;
```

This is my 'main'

```
void Ex3()
{ 
    Three* arr = NULL;
    ListThree* head = NULL;
    createArrayAndList(matrix,rows,cols,&head,&arr);
}
```

This function createArrayAndList:

```
int createArrayAndList(int** matrix,int rows, int cols, ListThree** head, Three** arr)
{
    int i, j, counter = 0;
    Three three;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == i + j)
            {
                counter++;
                three = createThree(matrix[i][j],i,j);
                *head = createThreeList(head,three);
            }
        }
    }
    *arr = createThreeArr(arr,head,counter);

    return counter;
}
```

Thanks guys, let me know if you would like me to provide more info.
I hope this is not a dumb question. :(

Comment: and what **createArrayAndList** is ?

Comment: Hey bruno I have added the function you asked.

Comment: *createThree* and *createThreeLIst* are also missing. In *Ex3* *matrix,rows* and *cols* refer to global vars ? how are they defined and initialized ?

Comment: I wanted not to exceed with unnecessary code the is not relate to my issue, but the matrix input is happen in different func and it worked fine. The only issue remains on the input in the function createThreeArr() . What is the proper way to return the array from createThreeArr() ?

Comment: yes but the problem can be in the hidden code. Anyway I found a problem in *createThreeArr*

Comment: is your definition of *next* in *ListThree* the right one ? If yes what is *List* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having

> ```
> typedef struct ListThree
> {
>   struct Three data;
>   struct List* next;
> }ListThree;
> ```

and

> ```
> Three* createThreeArr(Three** arr, ListThree** head, int counter)
> {
>     int i = 0;
>     ListThree* pIndex = *head;
> ```

in *createThreeArr* the assignment

> ```
>  pIndex = pIndex->next;
> ```

is invalid because `pIndex->next` values a `struct List*` rather than a `ListThree*`